# update_term_meta() works not as expected

Tags: php, database, wordpress

i'm trying to create a cron job that will write to DB and store new value and a previous one, on different rows each. But somehow every time the cron job is finished both values are the same (decrease and increase proportionately). Here is the code:

```
function getytdata() {

 global $wpdb;

 $ids = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT term_id, meta_value FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'termmeta WHERE meta_key =\'channelid\'' );

 $api_key = "###";

  foreach ($ids as $id) {

   $channel_id = $id->meta_value;
   $channel_bd_id =  $id->term_id;

   $api_response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/###');
   $api_response_decoded = json_decode($api_response, true);

   //subscriberCount

   $current = $api_response_decoded['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'];
   $yesterday =  get_term_meta( $channel_bd_id, 'subscribers', true );

   update_term_meta($channel_bd_id , 'subsyesterday', $yesterday);
   update_term_meta($channel_bd_id , 'subscribers', $current);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `add_term_meta()` to add new row each time

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention that but i don't need new rows each time, it should be two rows which get updated every time cron executes